# what rules database in firebase for user can read & right and admin can read database?

Tags: android, firebase

My firebase database rule is like the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the user to read and write and also the admin to only read the database. If so, the rules you provided allowed for any unauthenticated user to read & write including admin

Comment: can you write the rules? thank you for the respond.@martinomburajr

Answer (score 0):

This rule will allow database read and write if user is authorized or logged in.

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This rule will allow database read and write without checking if the user is authorized.

```
{
   "rules": {
     ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true"
   }
 }
```